# Can req.headers['user-agent'] be undefined in node.js production env?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, user-agent

We have a web app built with sails.js framework.

We had an an issue in production a couple of times where the `user-agent` was `undefined`.

```
let ua = req.headers['user-agent'];
```

I'm just trying to identify that in which cases `user-agent` will be `undefined`.

Comment: The short answer is **Yes**.

Comment: Since it is just a header parameter sent by the client, any time the client does not send one seems like a good start.

Comment: When an article of our website is shared on to a social mediums. Clicking on the shared link has no user-agent. Reasons unknown.